# create custom collection in magento

Tags: magento, collections, adminhtml

We have a table with delivery dates and i want to add it to the adminhtml in sales/order/grid.
The problem that i have is that the left join examples dont work for me and im out of options.

```
Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

**The method im trying now is to create  a custom query in _prepareCollection()**

```
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM mage_sales_flat_order_grid
              left join mage_aw_deliverydate_delivery
              on mage_sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id =  
              mage_aw_deliverydate_delivery.order_id';

    $collection = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

   //$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
   //$this->setCollection($collection);
   return parent::_prepareCollection();
```

**Then i add this column code in _prepareColumns()**

```
    $this->addColumn('delivery_date', array(
        'header' => 'delivery_date',
        'index' => 'delivery_date',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'width' => '100px',
    ));
```

I dont even see the new column when i look at the orders grid in the backoffice.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you want to add mage_aw_deliverydate_delivery to sales grid table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the anthor table

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

       $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('aw_deliverydate_delivery', 'main_table.entity_id = aw_deliverydate_delivery.order_id',array('*' ) );
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

And  the below code in _prepareColumns()

```
 $this->addColumn('aw_deliverydate_delivery', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Delivery Date '),
            'index' => 'aw_deliverydate_delivery',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',

        ));
```

Comment: I tried this but i get no results, the column is not added and i get no erros

Comment: I get no error, the page just loads like nothing changed. when i print the collection and insert into sql it works and i see the delivery_date column